# Android Screen Touch Action

Tags: android, touch-event

I am working on an android project where I need to know if user is Touch Down the screen or Touch Up the screen and I frequently need this. How can I do that?
I used on Touch Event in switch case for action Up and action down but that works for only one time. I also tried the bellow code but it gives me the the value of var(int variable) for first touch only.

my code:

```
int var=-1;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction();

    if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)var=1;
    if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)var=0;
    if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)var=1;

    return super.onTouchEvent(event); 
}
```

I need the value of var again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `onTouchEvent` is the last point of touch event traversal, it might not be called if one of the children has consumed touch  event already (of if you returned `false` for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event indicating that you are not interested in this gesture at all).

For your problem I would rather use `dispatchTouchEvent()` instead of `onTouchEvent()` and track touches there.

For more information I highly recommend getting yourself familiar with [talk from Dave Smith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI) about Android Touch System